Battery pack won't charge because it reads 4.2 V
I salvaged a battery pack from an IP camera and I want to know if it's in good shape to use for other stuff.

The packaging indicates a nominal voltage of 3.8 V and a capacity of 5000 mAh. I assume it's 3 LiIon cells in parallel, despite the arrangement of the connector.
With no load connected it reads 4.2 V.
Using a digital load tester to apply a 0.5 A load it dropped to 3.3 V and after about 30 mins it dropped to <3.2 V, so I assume it's in good shape after being stored for about a year.
The problem is that when I tried to charge it using a Q6 nano charger it went into trickle charge mode because it reads a voltage of 4.2 V, i.e. the screen went from orange to green right away and it shows small bursts of 5V-0.5 A every second or so.
How can I go about charging this pack?
Edit:
After cutting it open:


the three cells could easily be completely separate

@jsotola care to elaborate? what does that have to do with the 4.2 V?

The pack is clearly 1 Series- N Parallel cells  (where N is unknown unless you can feel the round cell under the packaging).  Make sure you connect to all the positive and all the negative wires on the cable from the battery pack when charging or discharging.  Other yellow and white wires are possibly thermistors in pack connected to ground for temperature sensing. Suggest you read about Li-Ion charging if you think charging a cell beyond 4.2V is desired. https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-409-charging-lithium-ion

@arielnmz three cells and three sets of black/red wires ... the cells may be completely separate inside the battery

@BK303 I never mentioned charging beyond 4.2 V I said it won't charge because it reads 4.2 V when no load is present, despite dropping to 3.2 V when under load.

fwiw: I cut it open and it was two 9.5 Wh3.8V cells in parallel

@arielnmz , I would think that 4.2V open-circuit voltage indicates the battery is chemically full, but I can't explain how one could draw 0.5A for 1/2 hour from a full battery, which is roughly 1 Whr (5% of capacity) from a battery labelled 20 Whr and not have the OC voltage drop to no more than 4.1V or 4.0V, because the capacity vs voltage curve is steep at the upper end of SOC for Li-Ion.  If you discharge further, certainly the OC voltage should drop more. A Li-Ion charger doesn't allow charging above 4.2V/cell for safety because that voltage normally indicates the cell is full.

@BK303 yes, that is exactly my question. How do I charge it if after the voltage drops to <3.2 V after using it for a bit it jumps back to 4.2 V when no load is applied?

My conclusion from the entire thread is that you didn't really discharge the battery enough for the charger to be able to add charge.  When you discharge longer, the battery charger should work.  Additionally, the pack has a very high internal resistance that is greatly reducing its ability to delivery power and possibly to charge fully.


Using a digital load tester to apply a 0.5 A load it dropped to 3.3 V and after about 30 mins it dropped to <3.2 V, so I assume it's in good shape after being stored for about a year.

This doesn't sound right to me. The battery capacity is 5000 mAh so with 500 mA load the discharge time should have been way higher despite the fact that the battery sat doing nothing for about a year.
A drop of ~1 V under 0.1C load and coming back to ~4.2V after removing the load could be a sign of death because dead batteries tend to have higher output resistances. This also may explain why the battery voltage under loading drops down to less than 3.2V after about half an hour – higher output resistance, higher drop therefore higher loss and ultimately higher temperature rise which may lead to an increase of the output resistance to bring even higher drop and lower effective battery voltage. If the battery pack contains a DW-01 (or a similar thing) battery protection board it might be cutting the circuit to stop discharging as it may think that the battery is overdischarged.

Is it common for cells to report higher voltages despite being discharged when they die? How can I tell apart a fully charged cell (4.2 V) from a dead one that measures 4.2 V without a digital load tester?

@arielnmz You can't - open-circuit voltage is an unreliable indicator of battery capacity. It's why all mobile devices use "coulomb counter" or "fuel gauge" ICs to monitor charge and discharge current over time to estimate battery capacity. To know whether a battery's internal resistance is still acceptable, you need at least a dummy load like a resistor.

I agree with Rohat that a 0.1C load should not result in a 1V drop (to 3.2V) at the cell output for a normally functioning Li-Ion battery.   Your load testing seems to indicate a higher than normal internal resistance.   Typical cell load dependent voltage drop per my quick review of a few datasheets seems to be about 0.3V drop or less at currents up to 1 C (5000 mA in this case).    Two possible indications of cell degradation are a decrease in total capacity OR an increase in the internal resistance, either of which mean the cell delivers less energy per cycle.

The question still remains, how can I even attempt to charge it if the charger measures 4.2 V?

@arielnmz Is it common for cells to report higher voltages despite being discharged when they die? No. Open-circuit voltage (VOC) can be used as an indication of state of charge (SoC), not state of health (SoH). How can I tell apart a fully charged cell (4.2 V) from a dead one that measures 4.2 V without a digital load tester? You can't. how can I even attempt to charge it if the charger measures 4.2 V? If the VOC is 4.2V then you should avoid attempting to recharge it. It's the safest VOC already which means full. Discharge it properly first, have its VOC low enough (e.g. less than 3V).

@RohatKılıç yes I think I figured it out yesterday, after splitting the package I managed to get a full discharge 1hr cycle @ 0.5 A out of one, and the voltage stayed at 3.9. It will take a couple more cycles until it is low enough to attempt recharging I guess

@arielnmz I managed to get a full discharge 1hr cycle @ 0.5 A out of one, and the voltage stayed at 3.9. I understand that the voltage stayed at 3.9V during the whole discharge period. For a 2.5Ah, 0.3V at 0.2C discharge rate doesn't look bad. Maybe the initial drop of ~1V came from the wires and interconnections.

I managed to get it to stay as low as 3.5 V by sipping 0.1 A for a couple of hours but it just won't charge. As soon as I try to even put 0.1 C into it the voltage starts jumping between 4-5V and the charger complains about the connection. If you could please add info or some reasons why it'd fail to charge I will accept this answer

@arielnmz what's the open-circuit voltage? What do you measure when it's unloaded? Is it 3.5V?

Some answers based on the things I learned since I posted the question:

I want to know if it's in good shape to use for other stuff.

The best way to know is using a digital load to measure the internal resistance and trying different load sizes.

So I assume it's in good shape after being stored for about a year.

It wasn't. For very small loads (0.1 C or so), it worked. For anything above 0.5 C, no. I learned this by trying different load sizes using the digital load device.

How can I go about charging this pack?

In the end it turned out that my Q6 "smart" charger was mostly faulty, too. I tried calibrating it but lack the proper equipment to do so and ended up using a dumb charging module, which worked just fine.

Battery pack won't charge because it reads 4.2 V

Zero-load voltage and the voltage under load vary depending on the battery's internal resistance. Chemically, it may seem fully charged and measure 4.2 V but only after connecting a load you will learn about its health. 1 C may make it drop to < 3.2 V right away but it may be able to sustain a 0.1 C load for longer.
In conclusion (some notes to myself that others may find useful):

Use a configurable digital load device.
Test for internal resistance at different loads (0.1, 0.2, 0.5 C, etc.)
Make sure the charger works and keep a good, known-working charging device around.


So really the conclusion should be not to rely on the voltage to indicate the state of charge but count the coulombs like phones do.

imo: the health of the battery is generally a combination of max voltage, internal resistance and runtime at different loads
